# UIPopoverBackgroundView without rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverbackgroundview

I am making a custom popover background by subclassing UIPopoverBackgroundView. I want to make popover without rounded corners. I can successfully create background without rounded corners (red in picture), but it seems that UIPopoverController adds some rounded corner mask to the content of the popover (green in picture). Here is the picture of the corner of my popover:

[image]

Any ideas how I can overcome it?

Comment: Try to set popoverLayoutMargins property of UIPopupviewController.

Comment: @Reformer thanks, but it didn't work for me

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found an easy solution, in the popover content controller (what you pass to `initWithContentViewController`) add:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is no longer working in iOS 10+, didn't check iOS 9.

Comment: yes dint work for me in iOS 12.2, any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an own PopoverBackgroundView. I have never used UIPopoverBackgroundView, but there's maybe a property for it, but otherwise you can do an own and set the view without rounded corners.

Comment: Is there any api? i did not find any api which will set without rounded corners inside UIPopoverBackgroundView?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can change green colour to clear colour and then add a UIView on pop over view, with greencolour and add all the other views as its subviews.(This is a tricky way)

Comment: thanks, but the popover content is scrollable so this solution won't work for me

Comment: have you took UIScrollView as a subview of pop over view?

Comment: The popover's content view controller is UIViewController with a table view in it